# What storage options exist for React Native apps on tvOS?

Tags: ios, react-native, redux, react-redux, tvos

I have a React Native app built for tvOS that uses `redux-persist`, however, I see the following message in the console every time my state changes:

`Persistent storage is not supported on tvOS, your data may be removed at any point.`

And yes, in fact, after testing, my app lost its state overnight.  Clearly Apple TV apps have some way of storing information, like who the user is.  Are they all are using some API that provides the current user's Apple ID and then storing their app state in the cloud?  Are there other options for storing state locally on the device?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, you can only use this to get 500kb of persistent storage on tvOS with react-native.

https://github.com/kevinresol/react-native-default-preference

Answer (score 0):

`AsyncStorage` for Redux allows to delegate its methods to your implementation on the native side (ObjC or Swift) with `RNCAsyncStorageDelegate` protocol.

For instance, you can store key-value pairs in `NSUserDefaults` for TvOS platform:

```objectivec
// AsyncStorageTvOS.h

#import <RNCAsyncStorage.h>

@interface AsyncStorageTvOS: NSObject<RNCAsyncStorageDelegate>

+ (instancetype)shared;

@end
```

```objectivec
// AsyncStorageTvOS.m

#import "AsyncStorageTvOS.h"

NSString* const AsyncStorageKey = @"async-storage";

@interface AsyncStorageTvOS ()

@property (nonatomic) NSMutableDictionary<NSString*, NSString*> *cache;

@end

@implementation AsyncStorageTvOS

+ (instancetype)shared {
  static dispatch_once_t once;
  static AsyncStorageTvOS *sharedInstance;
  dispatch_once(&once, ^{
    sharedInstance = [AsyncStorageTvOS new];
  });
  return sharedInstance;
}

- (instancetype)init {
  if (self = [super init]) {
    id dict = [NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults valueForKey:AsyncStorageKey];
    self.cache = dict ? [dict mutableCopy] : [NSMutableDictionary new];
  }
  return self;
}

- (void)save {
  [NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults setValue:self.cache forKey:AsyncStorageKey];
  [NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults synchronize];
}

- (void)allKeys:(RNCAsyncStorageResultCallback)block {
  NSArray<NSString*> *keys = self.cache.allKeys;
  block(keys);
}

- (void)mergeValues:(NSArray<NSString *> *)values
            forKeys:(NSArray<NSString *> *)keys
         completion:(RNCAsyncStorageResultCallback)block {
  // ...
}

- (void)removeAllValues:(RNCAsyncStorageCompletion)block {
  [self.cache removeAllObjects];
  block(nil);
  [self save];
}

- (void)removeValuesForKeys:(NSArray<NSString *> *)keys
                 completion:(RNCAsyncStorageResultCallback)block {
  for (NSString* key in keys) {
    [self.cache removeObjectForKey:key];
  }
  block(@[]);
  [self save];
}

- (void)setValues:(NSArray<NSString *> *)values
          forKeys:(NSArray<NSString *> *)keys
       completion:(RNCAsyncStorageResultCallback)block {
  
  for (NSUInteger i=0; i < keys.count; ++i) {
    NSString* key = keys[i];
    NSString* value = values[i];
    self.cache[key] = value;
  }
  block(@[]);
  [self save];
}

- (void)valuesForKeys:(NSArray<NSString *> *)keys completion:(RNCAsyncStorageResultCallback)block {
  NSMutableArray *values = [NSMutableArray new];
  for (NSString* key in keys) {
    NSString* value = self.cache[key];
    [values addObject:value ? value : [NSNull new]];
  }
  block(values);
}

- (BOOL)isPassthrough {
  return NO;
}

@end
```

Now you should set your delegate instance to `AsyncStorage` via React bridge:

```objectivec
#import <RNCAsyncStorage.h>

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
  // ...

  let bridge = [[RCTBridge alloc] initWithDelegate:self launchOptions:launchOptions];
  
#if TARGET_OS_TV
  RNCAsyncStorage* asyncStorage = [bridge moduleForClass:RNCAsyncStorage.class];
  asyncStorage.delegate = AsyncStorageTvOS.shared;
#endif
  // ...
}
```